# How to transform a quickdraw image to 84 by 84 in pytorch using the learn2learn library?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, learn2learn

I was trying to use learn2learn's QuickDraw but it seems like I'm getting errors when I attempt to apply transformations (resizing to 84x84, random crop) on it. The issue stems from when l2l's quickdraw library attempts to apply transformations onto a quickdraw image (that is apparently in the form of a np.memmap/.npy record that PIL can't understand) and so I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pzy2/diversity-for-predictive-success-of-meta-learning/div_src/diversity_src/dataloaders/maml_patricks_l2l.py", line 2300, in <module>
    loop_through_l2l_indexable_benchmark_with_model_test()
  File "/home/pzy2/diversity-for-predictive-success-of-meta-learning/div_src/diversity_src/dataloaders/maml_patricks_l2l.py", line 2259, in loop_through_l2l_indexable_benchmark_with_model_test
    for benchmark in [quickdraw_l2l_tasksets()]: #hdb8_l2l_tasksets(),hdb9_l2l_tasksets(), delaunay_l2l_tasksets()]:#[dtd_l2l_tasksets(), cu_birds_l2l_tasksets(), fc100_l2l_tasksets()]:
  File "/home/pzy2/diversity-for-predictive-success-of-meta-learning/div_src/diversity_src/dataloaders/maml_patricks_l2l.py", line 2216, in quickdraw_l2l_tasksets
    _transforms: tuple[TaskTransform, TaskTransform, TaskTransform] = get_task_transforms_quickdraw(_datasets,
  File "/home/pzy2/diversity-for-predictive-success-of-meta-learning/div_src/diversity_src/dataloaders/maml_patricks_l2l.py", line 2184, in get_task_transforms_quickdraw
    train_transforms: TaskTransform = DifferentTaskTransformIndexableForEachDataset(train_dataset,
  File "/home/pzy2/diversity-for-predictive-success-of-meta-learning/div_src/diversity_src/dataloaders/common.py", line 130, in __init__
    self.indexable_dataset = MetaDataset(indexable_dataset)
  File "learn2learn/data/meta_dataset.pyx", line 59, in learn2learn.data.meta_dataset.MetaDataset.__init__
  File "learn2learn/data/meta_dataset.pyx", line 96, in learn2learn.data.meta_dataset.MetaDataset.create_bookkeeping
  File "learn2learn/data/meta_dataset.pyx", line 65, in learn2learn.data.meta_dataset.MetaDataset.__getitem__
  File "/home/pzy2/miniconda3/envs/metalearning3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/learn2learn/vision/datasets/quickdraw.py", line 511, in __getitem__
    image = self.transform(image)
  File "/home/pzy2/miniconda3/envs/metalearning3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torchvision/transforms/transforms.py", line 60, in __call__
    img = t(img)
  File "/home/pzy2/miniconda3/envs/metalearning3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1051, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pzy2/miniconda3/envs/metalearning3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torchvision/transforms/transforms.py", line 900, in forward
    i, j, h, w = self.get_params(img, self.scale, self.ratio)
  File "/home/pzy2/miniconda3/envs/metalearning3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torchvision/transforms/transforms.py", line 859, in get_params
    width, height = F._get_image_size(img)
  File "/home/pzy2/miniconda3/envs/metalearning3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torchvision/transforms/functional.py", line 67, in _get_image_size
    return F_pil._get_image_size(img)
  File "/home/pzy2/miniconda3/envs/metalearning3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torchvision/transforms/functional_pil.py", line 26, in _get_image_size
    raise TypeError("Unexpected type {}".format(type(img)))
TypeError: Unexpected type <class 'numpy.memmap'>
```

original:

- https://github.com/learnables/learn2learn/issues/392
- https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-transform-a-quickdraw-image-to-84-by-84-in-pytorch-using-the-learn2learn-library/178292

Comment: Could you please support your problem with a small example to be able to answer your question with an example?

Comment: Without seeing code it is rather impossible. Apparently PIL doesn't get the `numpy.memmap` form, but who knows.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the numpy.memmap object to a NumPy array and then to a PIL image.

Comment: what would be the pytorch data transforms?

Comment: Sure, use the `torchvision.transforms` to compose on it a pipeline with `resize` then `RandomCrop`, then `ToTensor`. Next you should apply the `NumpyToTensor()` from `learn2learn.data.transforms` on your image before feeding it to the `transform` pipeline defined before. Hope it helps

Comment: The same transform has to work for quick draw and imagenet and cigar. How to do that?

Comment: Can you show what did you try

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `torchvision.transforms.ToTensor` this is not possible directly, because as stated in the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/vision/main/generated/torchvision.transforms.ToTensor.html)

> this transformation should not be used when transforming target image masks

check out [this](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/main/references/segmentation/transforms.py) instead to see the proper way of resizing

And here is an example quoted from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56748776/16930239):

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import torch
>>> np_arr = np.ones((5289, 38))
>>> torch_tensor = torch.from_numpy(np_arr).long()
>>> type(np_arr)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
>>> type(torch_tensor)
<class 'torch.Tensor'>
```

Comment: The same transform has to work for quick draw and imagenet and cigar. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

try this code out and let me know how it goes

```
import torch
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from PIL import Image
from learn2learn.data import QuickDraw

quickdraw = QuickDraw(root='path/to/quickdraw/data', train=True, transform=None)
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize(84),
    transforms.CenterCrop(84),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
])

# Get an example QuickDraw image
img, _ = quickdraw[0]

# Convert to PIL image
img = Image.fromarray(img)

# Apply transform
img = transform(img)

# Add a batch dimension
img = img.unsqueeze(0)

# Display the transformed image
print(img.shape)  # torch.Size([1, 1, 84, 84])
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the lack of code I will get some inspiration from your [issue #333](https://github.com/learnables/learn2learn/blob/master/learn2learn/vision/datasets/mini_imagenet.py) one year ago. I guess it changed a lot and you are not working on the same thing. Although, I think you kept the basic data structure.

You want to create your `MetaDataset` based on your QuickDraw dataset. I do not think QuickDraw can be indexed directly by `MetaDataset` because `MetaDataset` [calls each element](https://github.com/learnables/learn2learn/blob/0b9d3a3d540646307ca5debf8ad9c79ffe975e1c/learn2learn/data/meta_dataset.pyx#L96). If you apply a **data** transform on a bad data format -> you get incompatibility.

Actually, if you look at quickdraw on the repo, the `MetaDataset` is not instantiate anywhere from it. This is because it does not work: this is your bug.

The problem is the following: how to do the book keeping (indexing) on quickdraw which seems to be very big compared to the other dataset?

I suggest you the following:

1. Perform the book keeping yourself based on the annotations file from the quickdraw repo. Then you can put it has an attribute to your new `QuickDraw` class. You won't have the (very long) book keeping in `MetaDataset`. This indexing can be stored in `.pkl` file so you can do it only once.
2. Then add a pre-transform only for QuickDraw. Actually, if you really do not want to touch your transform in your class, let's say, I do not know your constraints, you can monkey patch the object, in worst case. But the more reasonable fix would be to insert into your **data** transform a function to convert the `np.memmap` to `PIL` or `Tensor` object.