# Validation data without targets

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, dataloader

I have a validation dataset of images to be classified by my CNN model. I want to load these images using `pytorch`. `torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder()` function doesn't work, since there are no targets, because the dataset is unclassified. I'm assuming that I need to write a custom dataset class, that I would later put in `torch.utils.data.DataLoader()`. I've searched online, but I'm still not really understanding how the class should look like.

I've tried this

```py
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
from torchvision.io import read_image
import os


class Dset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, dir: str, transform=None) -> None:
        self.transform = transform
        self.images = os.listdir(dir)
        self.dir = dir
    
    def __getitem__(self, index: int) -> torch.Tensor:
        image = read_image(f'{self.dir}/{self.images[index]}')
        if self.transform is not None:
            image = self.transform(image)
        return image

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return len(self.images)
```

But after this cell (all images are in `.data/`)

```py
from torchvision import transforms

batch_size = 64
transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.Grayscale(), transforms.ToTensor()])
data = Dset('data', transform=transform)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(data, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

images, labels = iter(trainloader)
```

I am encountering this error: `TypeError: Input image tensor permitted channel values are [1, 3], but found 4`

**Update**

```py
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
from torchvision.io import read_image, ImageReadMode
import os


class Dset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, dir: str, transform=None) -> None:
        self.transform = transform
        self.images = os.listdir(dir)
        self.dir = dir
    
    def __getitem__(self, index: int) -> torch.Tensor:
        image = read_image(f'{self.dir}/{self.images[index]}', mode=ImageReadMode.RGB)
        if self.transform is not None:
            image = self.transform(image)
        return image

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return len(self.images)
```

The error was caused by the alpha channel in the images.

After fixing that, I'm encountering this: `TypeError: pic should be PIL Image or ndarray. Got <class 'torch.Tensor'>`

**Update 2**

```py
from torchvision import transforms

batch_size = 64
transform = transforms.Compose(
[transforms.ToPILImage(), transforms.Resize((512, 512)),
transforms.Grayscale(), transforms.ToTensor()]
)
data = Dset('data', transform=transform)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(data, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

images = iter(trainloader)[0]
```

`torchvision.transforms.ToTensor` only converts PIL Image or `numpy.ndarray` to tensor.

Last line results in: `TypeError: '_SingleProcessDataLoaderIter' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: Could you try setting the `num_output_channels = 1 or 3` in `transforms.Grayscale()` explicitly and check if it resolves the issue?

Comment: @VikasSharma tried that, did not resolve the issue :(

Comment: Could you please share the shape of your images?

Comment: @VikasSharma images are RGB, 512 by 512 pixels, so that should be a (3, 512, 512) shape tensor

Comment: @VikasSharma I'm sorry, I have just loaded an image using `read_image()` from the dataset. It shows that image is (4, 512, 512)...

Comment: Oh okay, that's what I was suspecting. Perhaps an alpha channel. You should try removing it and check again.

Comment: Add `, mode: ImageReadMode.RGB` in your `read_image()` function.

Comment: @VikasSharma Thanks! Now I get a different error...

Comment: Please don't remove the previous errors or my answer will look out of context :) You may add the additional changes as an update. Thanks and I'll take a look at the new error.

Comment: @ I'm sorry about that, I will change it back

Comment: For the new error kindly check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56741108/pytorch-getting-the-typeerror-pic-should-be-pil-image-or-ndarray-got-class

Comment: @VikasSharma Thank you, that is very helpful! Unfortunately, after adding `transforms.ToPILImage(), transforms.Resize((512, 512))` to `transforms.Compose()`, I still cannot access images through `trainloader`... I get `TypeError: '_SingleProcessDataLoaderIter' object is not subscriptable` :(

Comment: Line that causes the error `images = iter(trainloader)[0]`

Comment: Check ***Update2*** in my answer for this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments - the issue is your images have an alpha channel. You can modify the `read_image` function to remove the alpha channel from the input images as follows:

```py
image = read_image(f'{self.dir}/{self.images[index]}', mode=ImageReadMode.RGB)
```

For other modes, you can check the [ImageReadMode class](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/generated/torchvision.io.ImageReadMode.html#torchvision.io.ImageReadMode).

***Update1:***

For the new error - according to the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/vision/main/generated/torchvision.transforms.ToTensor.html):

> ToTensor class converts a PIL Image or ndarray to tensor and scale the values accordingly.

But here you are providing `tensor` as an input instead of the required PIL image or ndarray.

To resolve this you may use the [ToPILImage](https://pytorch.org/vision/main/generated/torchvision.transforms.ToPILImage.html) method.

***Update2:***

For the error: `TypeError: '_SingleProcessDataLoaderIter' object is not subscriptable`

Check how to [Iterate through a DataLoader](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/data_tutorial.html#iterate-through-the-dataloader) from the PyTorch tutorials.

Also, you may try using a for loop as well to iterate as follows:

```
for images in trainloader:
    # Process images here
    break # update this break statement as per your requirement
```

Comment: I'm assuming since I don't have the labels, it should be: `for images in trainloader:`. Code above results in error: `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Comment: No, even if you don't have labels you'll have to unpack both the values. Hence, the error. Just for brevity, I have replaced `labels` with underscore.

Comment: Underscore still results in error...

Comment: Oh, what's the error?

Comment: `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`, if there is no underscore, then it works fine

Comment: My bad. You are right If you don't have any labels then `for images in trainloader:` should work fine.

Comment: Updated the for loop in my answer. Anyways, is everything in the scope of the question you asked resolved?